# using python multiprocessing package inside a qgis plugin code

Tags: python, plugins, python-multiprocessing, qgis

I spent quite a bit of time looking on how to use the multiprocessing package, but couldn't find anything on how to use it inside a plugin in QGIS. I am developing a plugin that does some optimization for several elements. I would like to parallelize it.

I found a useful link on multi-threading inside a python plugin (http://snorf.net/blog/2013/12/07/multithreading-in-qgis-python-plugins/), but nothing on using the multiprocessing module, which might be easier?

I have been trying with a very basic example. I am only showing the run function from the plugin here:

```
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()

    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()

    # See if OK was pressed and run code
    if result:
        #Get number of cores
        nProcs = mp.cpu_count()

        #Start a Process
        p = mp.Pool(nProcs)

        #Define function     
        def cube(x):
            return x**3

        #Run parallel        
        results = p.map(cube, range(1,7))
```

When I run this code from the plugin in QGIS, it opens several QGIS windows, which then return errors (can't load layers, etc.). What am I missing? Do I need to start a worker first on another thread and then use multiprocessing there? Or would we use another function from multiprocessing?

Please let me know if the question needs edits. I am working under windows 7, using QGIS 2.10.

Thanks,

**UPDATE**
I created a worker class to implement the function and sent it to a new thread, but I get the same problem when I use multiprocessing in that thread.

The class I created is as follows:

```
class Worker(QObject):
    '''Example worker'''
    def __init__(self, result_queue, f, attr=[], repet=None, nbCores=None):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        if not hasattr(f, '__call__'):
            #Check if not a function
            raise TypeError('Worker expected a function as second argument')
        if not isinstance(attr, list) and not repet==None:
            #Check if not a list if there is a repet command
            raise TypeError('Input problem:\nThe arguments for the function should be in a list if repet is provided')
        if not all(isinstance(elem, list) for elem in attr) and repet==None and len(inspect.getargspec(f).args) > 1:
            #Check if not a list of lists if there isn't a repet command
            raise TypeError('Input problem:\nThe arguments for the function should be a list of lists if repet is not provided')
        if not repet == None and (not isinstance(repet, int) or repet == 0):
            #Check that provided an integer greater than 0
            raise TypeError('If provided, repet should be None or a strictly positive integer')
        self.result_queue = result_queue
        self.f = f
        self.attr = attr
        self.repet = repet
        self.nbCores = nbCores

        if self.nbCores == None:
            self.nbCores = mp.cpu_count() - 1

    def fStar(self, arg):
        """Convert the function to taking a list as arguments"""
        return self.f(*arg)

    def run(self):
        ret = None
        try:
            if self.repet == 1:
                # estimates the function based on provided arguments
                ret = self.f(*self.attr) #The star unpacks the list into attributes
            else:
                pool = mp.Pool(processes=self.nbCores)

                if self.repet > 1:
                    ret = pool.map(self.fStar, itools.repeat(self.attr,self.repet))
                elif self.repet == None:
                    ret = pool.map(self.fStar, self.attr)

                pool.close()
                pool.join()
        except Exception, e:
            #I can't pass an exception, it makes qgis bug
            pass

        self.result_queue.put(ret) #Pass the result to the queue

    finished = pyqtSignal(object)
    error = pyqtSignal(Exception, basestring)
```

I start the worker and send it to a new thread using the following function:

```
def startWorker(f, attr, repet=None, nbCores=None):
    #Create a result queue
    result_queue = queue.Queue()

    # create a new worker instance
    worker = Worker(result_queue, f, attr, repet, nbCores)

    # start the worker in a new thread
    thread = QThread()
    worker.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(worker.run)
    thread.start()
    #Clean up when the thread is finished
    worker.deleteLater()
    thread.quit()
    thread.wait()
    thread.deleteLater()

    #Export the result to the queue
    res = []
    while not result_queue.empty():
        r = result_queue.get()
        if r is None:
            continue
        res.append(r)

    return res
```

As in my initial question, I just replaced `results = p.map(cube, range(1,7))` by calling the `startWorker` function

Please let me know if you have any idea how to make this work. I implemented the work in multiple threads, but it would be much faster to use several cores...